# Drag and drop image from a PictureBox to another PictureBox and check if is the target PictureBox is the correct one

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm new to programming. I'm making an application for first-grade kids in Visual Studio 2019 `WindowsForm` and one level is about dragging a picture from a `PictureBox` in an empty `PictureBox` that has a label with a simple definition.

So if I have 2 `PictureBox` that show let say a dog and a chicken and 2 empty `PictureBox` (1 with label "bones" and one with label "grain"). I want to drag the dog picture into the `PictureBox` with the label "bones" and the chicken in the one with "grain" label and if correct I show a text "great job" and if not I show a text "try again".

I can drag the pictures but I can't find a method to check if is correct.
Can anybody help me with that?

Here is my code so far:

```
    private void NivelulDoi_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            customPictureBox1.AllowDrop = true;
            customPictureBox2.AllowDrop = true;
            customPictureBox3.AllowDrop = true;
        }

        private void customPictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                customPictureBox1.DoDragDrop(customPictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }

        private void customPictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            if (data != null)
            {
                var fileNames = data as string[];
                if (fileNames.Length > 0)
                {
                    customPictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(fileNames[0]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void customPictureBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }

        private void customPictureBox2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Dragging(e);
        }

        private void customPictureBox2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            customPictureBox2.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
            
            // figure out how to check if correct 
            /*if (customPictureBox2.Image == (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true))
            {
                label1.Text = "ai reusit";
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "mai incearca";
            }*/   
        }

        private void customPictureBox3_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Dragging(e);
        }

        private void customPictureBox3_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            customPictureBox3.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
        }

        private void customPictureBox4_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Dragging(e);
        }

        private void customPictureBox4_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            customPictureBox4.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
        }

        private static void Dragging(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) && (e.AllowedEffect & DragDropEffects.Copy) != 0)
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Best store the image name of some other key in each pbox's Tag property. Once an Image is in the PBox there is not (reasonable) way to determine which image it is.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to define a variable to save the Name of "picturebox drag" and a dictionary to save "drag-drop" pair.

Here is the demo.

```
string pictureBoxFrom = "";
Dictionary<string, string> picDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox2.AllowDrop = true;
    pictureBox4.AllowDrop = true;
    pictureBox1.MouseDown += pictureBox_MouseDown;
    pictureBox3.MouseDown += pictureBox_MouseDown;
    pictureBox2.DragEnter += pictureBox_DragEnter;
    pictureBox2.DragDrop += pictureBox_DragDrop;
    pictureBox4.DragEnter += pictureBox_DragEnter;
    pictureBox4.DragDrop += pictureBox_DragDrop;

    picDict.Add("pictureBox1", "pictureBox2"); // drag 1 to 2
    picDict.Add("pictureBox3", "pictureBox4"); // drag 3 to 4
}

private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBoxFrom = (sender as PictureBox).Name;
    var img = (sender as PictureBox).Image;
    if (img == null) return;
    if (DoDragDrop(img, DragDropEffects.Move) == DragDropEffects.Move)
    {
        //(sender as PictureBox).Image = null;
    }
}

private void pictureBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void pictureBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (picDict.ContainsKey(pictureBoxFrom) && picDict[pictureBoxFrom].Equals((sender as PictureBox).Name))
    {
        var bmp = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
        (sender as PictureBox).Image = bmp;
        MessageBox.Show("great job");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("try again");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the help.